# back button without calling finish() or onBackPressed()

Tags: java, android, button, activity-finish, onbackpressed

I want to create a button to go back to the previous activity,
but if I use the methods "finish()" or "onBackPressed()" in the "onclick" event, each time I press the button I have the message from the system
"unfortunately, activity has stopped". Is there an alternative way to introduce a back button, without showing messages such as this which could be taken for message errors from the user?

Here is my xml for the button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="back"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:onClick="onBackPressed"
    />
```

No more code is needed, because the onBackPressed already exists in the library.

Comment: plz, post your code and the stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the same activity always starts your current one, just hard code it...

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, PreviousActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Otherwise you can pass extras in your intents to let you know, and then make a conditional method to start the correct one. Also I'd write all your button code in your java files, but that's more a personal preference I guess.

```
//global declaration
Button GameButton;

//onCreate
GameButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.GameButton);
GameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your code
        }
    });
```

Comment: then you find what you missing or not?